# WPF Setting property to its default value

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

In WPF, Does setting a default value to the property have performance impact?

For example :
SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonRed" Color="#FFEF0137" Opacity="1"

As default value for Opacity is 1, does setting the value again a bad practise?

Comment: Depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve. Explicitly setting `Opacity="1"` will have higher precedence than an Opacity value from a Style Setter, thus making such a Style Setter ineffective. You may or may not want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does setting a default value to the property have performance impact?

No. At least not in practice, i.e. it's not something that you will notice or even be able to measure.

Theoretically speaking, it's another attribute (some more text/bytes) for the XAML processor to parse and handle.

> As default value for Opacity is 1, does setting the value again a bad practise?

I don't know if I would call it bad practice but it's certainly unnecessary.

As mentioned in a comment, local values take [precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/dependency-property-value-precedence?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) over values set by styles even of this doesn't apply to brushes.

When it comes to performance, the general rule of thumb is that you should first identify a performance *issue* before you start to optimze the actual bottleneck. Setting properties of XAML resources isn't likely to be a performance killer.